# How to get Last digit of number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to extract last(end) digit of the Number value using jquery. 
because i have to check the last digit of number is 0 or 5. so how to get last digit after decimal point

For Ex.
`var test = 2354.55` Now how to get 5 from this numeric value using jquery.
i tried **substr** but that is only work for string not for Number format

Like if i am use `var test = "2354.55";`

then it will work but if i use `var test = 2354.55` then it will not.

Comment: the expression `test + ''` will return a string representation of the number

Comment: If rounding the number is the only purpose then there are better options to do so...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
var test = 2354.55;
var lastone = +test.toString().split('').pop();

console.log("lastone-->", lastone, "<--typeof", typeof lastone);

// with es6 tagged template and es6 spread
let getLastDigit = (str, num)=>{
  return num.toString();
};
let test2 = 2354.55;
let lastone2 = +[...getLastDigit`${test2}`].pop();

console.log("lastone2-->", lastone2, "<--typeof", typeof lastone2);
```

---

Updates with ES6/ES2015:

We can use tagged template in such case as numbers are not iterable. So, we need to convert the number to a string representation of it. Then just spread it and get the last number popped.

Comment: how to get last two numbers (or x numbers)

Comment: I'm curious about the efficiency of this versus modulus (which is normally slow, but mod 10 should be logically fast).

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, I was also curious, so I created a benchmark test, modulo appears to be the fastest. See for yourself: http://jsben.ch/HFS4t

Comment: This also sets the variable to a string vs a number

Comment: this function does't work if it's like 2.2313961097670283e+31 it should return 7 not 1

Answer (score 75):

This worked for us:

```js
var sampleNumber = 123456789,
  lastDigit = sampleNumber % 10;
console.log('The last digit of ', sampleNumber, ' is ', lastDigit);
```

Works for decimals:

```js
var sampleNumber = 12345678.89,
  lastDigit = Number.isInteger(sampleNumber) ? sampleNumber % 10
    : sampleNumber.toString().slice(-1);
console.log('The last digit of ', sampleNumber, ' is ', lastDigit);
```

Click on Run code snippet to verify.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for pointing this out. Do you have some idea to accommodate decimals? [Please suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48319841/edit) - I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Just suggested an edit, maybe this is a bit double because .slice(-1) already works with every number but I would guess that this will perform better when % 10 is used (could be totally wrong haha). Would be cool to make it work without converting it to a string but would have to think a bit longer about that :)

Answer (score 14):

you can just convert to string

```
var toText = test.toString(); //convert to string
var lastChar = toText.slice(-1); //gets last character
var lastDigit = +(lastChar); //convert last character to number

console.log(lastDigit); //5
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is another one using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var test = 2354.55;
var lastDigit = test.toString().slice(-1);
//OR
//var lastDigit = (test + '').slice(-1);

alert(lastDigit);
```

Comment: if number is `123405` & we want last two digits, it will return `5` instead of `05` bcz 0 is removed while converting to number.

Answer (score 8):

Just in one line.

```js
const getLastDigit = num => +(num + '').slice(-1);

console.log(getLastDigit(12345)) // Expect 5
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a JS function `.charAt()` you can use that to find the last digit

```js
var num = 23.56
var str = num.toString();
var lastDigit = str.charAt(str.length-1);
alert(lastDigit);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the digit **in the hundredths place**, then you can do the following:

```
test * 100 % 10
```

The problem with convert to string and getting the last digit is that it does not give the hundredths place value for whole numbers.

Comment: @joyBlanks good question, for some reason I assumed these were currency values.  If not, could use `Math.floor(test * 100 % 10)`

Comment: @dave: +1! Your answer could be even easier.  test % 10. =)

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` converts number to string, and `charAt()` gives you the character at a particular position.

```js
var str = 3232.43;
lastnum = str.toString().charAt( str.length - 1 );
alert( lastnum );
```