# How to get the last digit of a number in jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have  number 22 with me. I wanted to get the last digit of this number.

```
var no = 22;
```

How to get the last digit 2 from this number ?

Comment: `no % 10` will do

Comment: Just keep dividing the number and then its remainder with 10 until the remainder becomes less than 10, that remainder will be the last digit.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the help of Modulus operator `%` like:

```
var no = 22;
var lastDigit = no%10;
```

```js
var cartno = 22; 
var onesOnly = parseInt(cartno % 10);
alert(onesOnly);
```

Comment: var cartno = 22;
var onesOnly = parseInt(cartno % 10); showing NaN

Comment: why you are doing parseInt over cartno % 10? Its not needed as we are dealing with numbers only. See, your code is working.

Comment: It seems like mathematical division solution is much efficient than that mentioned on  fiddle @Insomania

Comment: @WasimBajwa modulo is mathematical operation right?

Comment: could you please post your complete code as it is here in question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
var number = 22;
var lastdigit = number.toString().split('').pop();
alert(lastdigit);
```

that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var no = 22
var lastdigit = no % 10 #contains last digit

console.log(lastdigit)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var no = 22;
console.log(parseInt(no%10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS function .charAt() you can use that to find the last digit. Credit to Kashyap
[How to get Last digit of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695991/how-to-get-last-digit-of-number)

```js
var num = 22;
var str = num.toString();
var lastDigit = str.charAt(str.length-1);
alert(lastDigit);
```